# How to ungroup a table in DolphinDB?

Tags: group-by, dolphindb, group

My question is: how to ungroup a table? i.e., how to convert a column of array vectors into a single-element column?

Here is my script:

```
t = table(1 2 3 as id, `IBM`MSFT`GOOG as sym,(2 3,4,5 6 7) as value)
```

---

```
id  sym value
1   IBM 2,3
2   MSFT    4
3   GOOG    5,6,7
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
id  sym value
1   IBM 2
1   IBM 3
2   MSFT    4
3   GOOG    5
3   GOOG    6
3   GOOG    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A built-in function will be released soon for this purpose. Now you can write a UDF to solve this problem.

```
def myungroup(t, listColName){
        expandIndex = loop(take, til(t.rows()), t[listColName].rowSize()).flatten()
        g = def(col, expandIndex){
                colType = col.type()
                if(colType == ANY || colType >= 64)        return col.flatten() else return col[expandIndex]
        }
        return each(g{,expandIndex}, t.flip()).flip()
}
t = table(1 2 3 as id, `IBM`MSFT`GOOG as sym,(2 3,4,5 6 7) as value)
myungroup(t, "value")
```